# Proyecto Java en Servidor IIS

Tags: java, iis

Tengo un proyecto Java EE, normalmente generaba un war y se pubicaba en un servidor weblogic, pero ahora la arquitectura estandarizada a nivel de servidores es Microsoft y requiero configurarlo para que se publicado en un servidor IIS, alguna sugerencia de que debo hacer o no es posible ello, gracias de antemano

Comment: Vas a necesitar un contenedor Java EE para tu aplicación, ya sea WebLogic o Tomcat. IIS puede hacer de servidor web, delegando las llamadas a tu aplicación (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/windows-server-azure-pack/mt125371(v=technet.10))

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.